# Why is the int class lowercase but the String class is not?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've noticed this across a few languages, but I'll make my question specific to AS3. Why is an int class lowercase but a String or Number is not?

```
var myInt:int = 0;
var myString:String = "";
var myNum:Number = 0;
```

Comment: My first guess would be that String and Number are objects and int is just a primitive type (my first language isn't AS3, though I do spend a decent amount of time in it now), but I just looked up that in AS3, there is an 'int' class.

Comment: Yes, int is a final class and extends Object. You can notice it because has methods as toFixed, valueOf, toString, toPrecision, and static costs as MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE and length, apart from what is inherited from Object.

Comment: Because it was designed by committee? ;)

Answer (score 3):

That's simply primitive values vs. Objects. You can do something like String.substring() because it's an Object but you can't do anything with int, it's just a number.

==== EDIT ====

According to the comment below, the int in AS3 is a class so you can call some methods of it. However, it is still a primitive type. The difference is explained here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/data-types.html

"Primitive values are usually faster than complex values because ActionScript 3 stores primitive values in a special way that makes memory and speed optimizations possible.

Note: For readers interested in the technical details, **ActionScript 3 stores primitive values internally as immutable objects.** The fact that they are stored as immutable objects means that **passing by reference is effectively the same as passing by value**. This cuts down on memory usage and increases execution speed, because references are usually significantly smaller than the values themselves."

Comment: no, that's wrong. values of type `String` and `int` are both primitive values in AS3. They both include methods, ie `int.toExponential`

Comment: Makes sense to me. So primitive values are lowercase by naming convention then?

Comment: Both String and int are primitive data types, so this doesn't really explain the naming difference.

Comment: well then... I guess I'm more confused

Comment: Yes, that is just a convention which AS3 tries to follow. But, Strings are not primitive by the means of storing their content. For example, you can have a 10-megabyte sized string, and obviously passing it by value would be ridiculous. Such string should be passed as a reference. Whereas an int can always be passed by value.

Comment: In AS3 all primitive (like string) are passed by value.

Comment: The docs say quite the opposite: "The fact that they are stored as immutable objects means that passing by reference is effectively the same as passing by value. This cuts down on memory usage and increases execution speed, because references are usually significantly smaller than the values themselves"

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko Did you miss the part of that article right before that? "ActionScript 3 has many data types to use as the type for the variables you create. **A primitive value is a value that belongs to one of the following data types: `String` , `Number` , `int` , `uint` , `Boolean` , `Null` , and `void` .**"

Comment: No I didn't miss it. I was answering the comment saying "In AS3 all primitive (like string) are passed by value". I am aware that AS3 String is also a primitive type, but what I'm saying is that according to AS3, primitive types are passed by reference (not by value). Therefore passing a 10-megabyte String is not a problem, as well as passing a simple int. But then, if we talk about primitive types in their "true" meaning (not AS3), a String cannot be primitive since it needs to be passed as a reference. AS3 just does a trick by passing (pseudo-) primitive types as references, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that they followed the [ECMAScript3 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) where you on page 14 of the PDF find the definition of primitive values of type `Number`, `String`, and `Boolean`.

Page 26 of the PDF lists future reserved keywords, where `int` appears. Naturally if they want to support unsigned integers, it should be called `uint`.

---

Personally I think it would make more sense to name them `Int` and `Uint` (or do like Java)

Comment: so they don't want you to name any variables "int"?

Comment: No, the standard simply says that if you want to use a dedicated type for integers, you should call `int` (at least indirectly)